# Key exchange after revoked certificate status

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I was trying to observe TLS flow if a website has a revoked certificate. Then I found a test website "https://revoked.grc.com/" and send a request over Google Chrome while I was capturing packets via Wireshark.

During TLS, the server (https://revoked.grc.com/) sent me a revoked certificate and certificate status which has "REVOKED", then I displayed "NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED" error on Google Chrome as I expected.

I have also expected to display an error like "Handshake Failure" or "Bad Certificate" on Wireshark, but when I filtered TLS flow on Wireshark, I saw that the key exchange is done!

[screen shot of wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEAXU.png)

Is there any idea why Wireshark capture is like that? Is it a security vulnerability of Google Chrome?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  It's because a certificate is valid as long as the signature is valid and the date is within the current valid range.  The only way a browser (or other system) knows that a certificate is revoked is to consult a CRL using OCSP or, as is often the case for a server, a local CRL.

If you mark a certificate as revoked in your PKI, you are creating an entry in the CRL.  The certificate itself is not changed.  If you had to change the certificate, you would have no way to revoke a certificate that you did not have physical possession of.